# Is there a cross-platform method to list the available serial ports?

Tags: c++, cross-platform

I'm creating software using C++ and the boost::asio library that requires access a serial port. I would like to create a GUI which includes choices for the serial port device name, such as `/dev/ttyUSB0` under Linux or `COM3:` under Windows.

So far, I've just put in simple text edit box so that the user can simply type the device name, but a user suggested that a combo-box would be a little more user-friendly.

Are there some kind of reasonably cross-platform methods by which to list the possible serial ports?

Comment: You could maybe try to open all the commonly-expected combinations?

Comment: @Martin: In theory, I could, but I'd prefer to avoid this.  Scanning ports on a device that may be, for example, part of an industrial control system, is generally frowned upon because even simply opening a port could change the states of some of the lines (e.g. RTS and DTR) which could have unintended physical consequences on controlled (but currently idle) equipment.

Comment: Hehe - your 'industrial control system' sucks if just changing the state of the control lines makes it do things.  Connectors fall out, workers drive nails into cables and drivers run into trunking with fork-lifts:)

Comment: @Martin: all true, and neither you nor I would ever design a system that way.  However, they exist, and I have to deal with that fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's nothing like this.

Your best bet is to have a platform specific confic file that lists the values to display in the combo box.